# Implementing Beer's law in a ray tracing render engine

Tags: absorption

I am a 3D artist and i work in the cycle render engine which is a ray tracing render engine.

I want to Implement Beer's law in my transparent materials.
I tried to do this based on my understanding of the law using the form (Absorbance = e L c)

And here is my implementation (I hope you understand how this node based system work)

[image: Mine]

The Apply A:B divide the ray length by 0.666 to get the right proportion for it as I understand from the internet.

The rest is just the calculation based on my understanding (Using soda lime glass as example).

Unfortunately the result is always wrong and I thing this is because I don't understand
the equation or I am applying it wrong way.

So can you please explain me this law and how can I implement it If we take Soda lime glass as an example. (I am just 15 so Please make it simple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Absorbed power.]

In the diagram above, a light beam with intensity $P_0$ shines through a transparent medium that absorbs light. The optical path length is $b$ (you called it $L$). Due to light absorption the intensity of the light beam is only $P (<P_0)$, when it has passed through the light absorbing medium.

$P_0$ and $P$ are usually determined by means of a light meter. When the transparent medium *is not inserted between the beam and the light meter* the latter will read $P_0$, but when it inserted between the beam and the light meter the latter will read $P$.

We now *define* the so-called absorbance $A$ as:

$$A=\log\frac{P_0}{P}.$$

Where $\log$ stands for *logarithm in the base of $10$*.

Now let us assume the light absorbance is caused by an ingredient dissolved into the transparent medium and that the molar concentration is $c$ (in $\mathrm{mol dm^{-3}}$ or $\mathrm{mol L^{-1}}$, if you prefer), then it is quite intuitive to understand that the higher the concentration is, the higher the absorbance will be, or:

$$A \propto c.$$

It is equally intuitive that the longer the optical path length $b$ is, the higher the absorbance will be, or:

$$A \propto b.$$

So we have:

$$A \propto bc.$$

What we need to complete this relationship is a *proportionality constant*, usually called $\epsilon$ (you called it $e$), so that:

$$A=\epsilon bc.$$

$\epsilon$ is a *material constant* intrinsic to the light absorbing dissolved ingredient (at concentration $c$) with measuring unit $\mathrm{Lmol^{-1}m^{-1}}$. In some cases $\epsilon$ is *a priori* knowledge, in other cases it needs to be experimentally determined by means of a calibration curve (by *measuring* repeatedly various ratios of $\frac{A}{bc}$).

No pun intended but it's as easy as ABC!

**Edit:**

In the specific case of the absorbance of soda glass (of constant composition) we can't use the concept of concentration but we can validly modify Beer's Law to:

$$A=\varepsilon  b.$$

Where $\varepsilon$ is simply a material constant, inherent to soda glass, call it *the specific absorbance of glass* and Beer's Law is now only dependent on optical path (for a given type of glass). It should be possible to find values for $\varepsilon$ for various types of glass on the Internet.

Comment: I got what you explained there,But practically If we take "Soda lime glass for example"what would be the parameters?
And for the ratio between the ray length and the concentration it in some sites they said they have the ration of 1:0.666,Is that right?

Comment: @OmarAhmad: edited in the answer to the first part of your question. Re. the second part I don't know whether that ratio is correct or where it is supposed to have come from. Perhaps from the fact that in spectrometry the optical path $b$ is set to a standard value of $1\:\mathrm{cm}$?